# id=setInterval() is first undefined than 3 (Uses Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I would like to have a counter, that counts backwards, and is stopped if the user filled the input-field.

Unfortunately the counter does not stop - I tried to read the counter ID on many places 
of the code and can't see the logic where it changes the value (Probably I have a wrong idea
how SetInterval() and clearInterval() works ...

The relevant part of the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var counter=0;
    function hole_erste_Frage(aktuelle_div, nr){
     $.ajax({
        url: 'gnkid.php',
        data: 'sectionid='+sectionid+'&nr='+nr,
        success: function(data)          
        {
          if ($('.dbantwort').eq(aktuelle_div).val().length>0) {
            console.log(counter); // "0"
            counter = start_counter($('.dbantwort').eq(aktuelle_div).val().length*2+5);
            console.log(counter); // "undefined" - WHY????
          }
        }
     });
    }
    hole_erste_Frage(aktuelle_div,aktuelle_div);
    function start_counter(count) {
        console.log(counter); // 1. call: "undefined" - 2. call: "3" !!! - Why 3??
        if (count<3) {count=3};
        var cnt=count*10;
        counter = setInterval(function() {
          console.log(counter); // still "undefined" than "3"
          if (cnt >= 0) {
                var sek=Math.floor(cnt/10);
                var zsek=cnt/10;
                if (sek<5){
                    $('#displayCounter').html(zsek);
                } else {
                    $('#displayCounter').html(sek);
                }
                cnt--;
                return_prevent--;
                question_time=question_time+100;
            }
            else {
                console.log(counter); // "undefined" - "3"            
                stop_counter(counter,'Timeout!!');                
            }
        }, 100);
        console.log(counter); // and still "undefined" - I don't understand!
     }
function stop_counter(cter,bool){
    clearInterval(counter);  // I think here is the problem, because when it is called the first time the variable "counter" seems to be "undefined"
    if (bool!='') {$('#displayCounter').html(bool);}
}
function press_send(){ // This one is called after the user pressed "return"
    stop_counter(counter); // Here is the problem - it does not stop "undefined" - and "3"
    if (check_answer()) {
        $('.Abfrage-Box').eq(aktuelle_div).toggle();
        check_answer_sql($('.antwort').eq(aktuelle_div).val(),$('.kid').eq(aktuelle_div).val(),aktuelle_div, question_time, true);
        aktuelle_div = (aktuelle_div>=anzahl_abfrageboxen-1) ? 0 : aktuelle_div+1;
        $('.Abfrage-Box').eq(aktuelle_div).toggle();
        $('.antwort').eq(aktuelle_div).focus();
        if ($('.dbantwort').eq(aktuelle_div).val().length>0) {
            console.log(counter);
            start_counter($('.dbantwort').eq(aktuelle_div).val().length*2+5);
            console.log(counter);
        }

    } else {
        check_answer_sql($('.antwort').eq(aktuelle_div).val(),$('.kid').eq(aktuelle_div).val(),aktuelle_div, question_time, false);
        $('.antwort').eq(aktuelle_div).css('backgroundColor','red');
        $('.richtige_antwort').eq(aktuelle_div).toggle();
    }

}
```

Comment: Sniff Sniff. I smell spaghetti.

Comment: Sorry for the mixture of German and English variable names - if that was what you were refering to?

Comment: Not quite, I meant [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code)

Comment: Ok, got now what you want to say-but unless you tell me more detailed WHY it looks like that (since I did not use any GOTO like in Basic - I use functions, don't I?) it is not a very helpful comment? - A bit more detailed what exactly wasn't right and how I could improve it would help much more?

Of course I would like to improve the structure of my code, since it makes it easier to find mistakes and get others to have a look onto it, so I would like to improve - but if you don't tell me WHAT was wrong it is a bit difficult?? -If I knew better I would have written different in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're assigning different values to counter...

I'd suggest adding a new variable outside of the functions, say `gCounterTimer`.  Whenever you call `setInterval(...)` assign it to this new variable, i.e.:

```
gCounterInterval = setInterval(...)
```

And then when you need to clear it use:

```
clearInterval(gCounterInterval)
```

So your code would look like this:

var gCounterInterval;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var counter=0;
    function hole_erste_Frage(aktuelle_div, nr){
     $.ajax({
        url: 'gnkid.php',
        data: 'sectionid='+sectionid+'&nr='+nr,
        success: function(data)          
        {
          if ($('.dbantwort').eq(aktuelle_div).val().length>0) {
            console.log(counter); // "0"
            counter = start_counter($('.dbantwort').eq(aktuelle_div).val().length*2+5);
            console.log(counter); // "undefined" - WHY????
          }
        }
     });
    }
    hole_erste_Frage(aktuelle_div,aktuelle_div);
    function start_counter(count) {
        console.log(counter); // 1. call: "undefined" - 2. call: "3" !!! - Why 3??
        if (count<3) {count=3};
        var cnt=count*10;
        gCounterInterval = setInterval(function() {
          console.log(counter); // still "undefined" than "3"
          if (cnt >= 0) {
                var sek=Math.floor(cnt/10);
                var zsek=cnt/10;
                if (sek<5){
                    $('#displayCounter').html(zsek);
                } else {
                    $('#displayCounter').html(sek);
                }
                cnt--;
                return_prevent--;
                question_time=question_time+100;
            }
            else {
                console.log(counter); // "undefined" - "3"            
                stop_counter(counter,'Timeout!!');                
            }
        }, 100);
        console.log(counter); // and still "undefined" - I don't understand!
     }
function stop_counter(cter,bool){
    clearInterval(gCounterInterval);  // I think here is the problem, because when it is called the first time the variable "counter" seems to be "undefined"
    if (bool!='') {$('#displayCounter').html(bool);}
}
function press_send(){ // This one is called after the user pressed "return"
    stop_counter(counter); // Here is the problem - it does not stop "undefined" - and "3"
    if (check_answer()) {
        $('.Abfrage-Box').eq(aktuelle_div).toggle();
        check_answer_sql($('.antwort').eq(aktuelle_div).val(),$('.kid').eq(aktuelle_div).val(),aktuelle_div, question_time, true);
        aktuelle_div = (aktuelle_div>=anzahl_abfrageboxen-1) ? 0 : aktuelle_div+1;
        $('.Abfrage-Box').eq(aktuelle_div).toggle();
        $('.antwort').eq(aktuelle_div).focus();
        if ($('.dbantwort').eq(aktuelle_div).val().length>0) {
            console.log(counter);
            start_counter($('.dbantwort').eq(aktuelle_div).val().length*2+5);
            console.log(counter);
        }

    } else {
        check_answer_sql($('.antwort').eq(aktuelle_div).val(),$('.kid').eq(aktuelle_div).val(),aktuelle_div, question_time, false);
        $('.antwort').eq(aktuelle_div).css('backgroundColor','red');
        $('.richtige_antwort').eq(aktuelle_div).toggle();
    }

}
```

Comment: I replaced "counter" by gCounterInterval now, but the result is the same :( 
I double checked several times, that I do not use the same variable name somewhere else.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the code - it's not a straight replacement of the counter variable by gCounterInterval

Comment: Ahhh - thanks a lot - yes, I called the function start_counter() with the same variable - stupid - many many thanks!! Searched for that since 3 afternoons - so blind!